# New environment for colored and small font-size

Tags: color, environments, fontsize

I am looking for a way to define a new environment in LaTeX that allows me to quickly write certain text passages in an altered way, such as smaller font-size and different color.

What i'm specifically looking for is to define an enrivonment such that i can, for example, write

```
\begin{smallredtext}
this is supposed to be red and font-size small.
\end{smallredtext}
```

I tried looking for existing solutions but couldn't find anything helpful so far. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\newenvironment{smallredtext}{\small\color{red}}{\par}`

Comment: oh wow, that was incredibly quick and exactly what i was looking for. Thank you David. I'll happily accept your comment as an answer, if you'd like to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `color` (or `xcolor`) package and

```
\newenvironment{smallredtext}{\small\color{red}}{\par}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @David. I'm allowed to accept your answer in a few minutes.